# How can I set a dropdown value as default value when the index page is loaded using js?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working in a wordpress template, and I want to set my dropdown menu value to usa as default value when the index page is completely loaded using jQuery to activate an other dropdown menu; this my function code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (jQuery('.car_form_search').length) {

    /* load locations 0 level */
    var loc_0 = jQuery('.qs_carlocation0');

    if (loc_0.length) {

      var data = {
        action: "app_cardealer_draw_quicksearch_locations",
        parent_id: 0,
        level: 0,
        selected_region: loc_0.eq(0).data('location0')
      };

      jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        if (response && response != '0') {
          loc_0.append(response);
        }
      });

    }
  }
```

This the form's screenshoot:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to set the default value after the `loc_0.append(response);` line, assuming that is the line that adds the markup to the page.  Without more information about the markup that is being inserted, advise towards the issue is kinda limited.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the snippet editor `<>` - do NOT post PHP but relevant rendered HTML - this is not a PHP question

Comment: If you have value="USA" then you can do `$("<selectorOfCountry>").val("USA").change()` to select AND trigger the change

Comment: this is the php code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxJZC.png

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `#country` is the `select` list of countries.
You can set it to a default value like this :

```
$('#country option[value="USA"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Then, to get the list of `states`, you need to fire the [change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

```
$('#country').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force a selection on the Country `<select>` using [`.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex), then trigger a `change` event.

```
$("[country select]")[0].selectedIndex = 1  // Set the correct index for USA
$("[country select]").trigger("change");
```

Change `[country select]` for the right selector in the above code.